# Hover effect background and font effects

Tags: html, css, hover

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```css
ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(151, 75, 31);
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<nav>           
    <ul>         
      <li><a href="#">Carrinho</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lupa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Free Training</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ShowQase</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Course</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>           
    </ul>           
</nav>
```

What I want is when I move the mouse over the `li` the font becomes white, not just when I move the mouse over the link a.

Thanks guys

Comment: move the hover to the li in the last selector `li:hover a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ul li:hover a`

```css
ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(151, 75, 31);
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

ul li:hover a {
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<nav>           
    <ul>         
      <li><a href="#">Carrinho</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lupa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Free Training</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ShowQase</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Course</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>           
    </ul>           
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
ul li a:hover {
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```

To:

```
ul li:hover a {
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```